# Slick 3 map Custom Type to Option

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I want to define a custom type X in Slick 3 that should be Mapped to Option[String].

At the moment I'm trying to use MappedColumnType.base[X, Option[String]], but Option[String] does not seem to be a "BaseColumnType".

I know, that Option[X] would be possible, but I prefer the other way...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100254/scala-slick-getting-a-typedtype-for-a-wrapped-optiont/